# Calculating collection data before rendering in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm really new to Meteor.js and I want to understand the basics. I want to do some calculations with the data in my collection and render it to the DOM. It should be rendered to the DOM with the {{#each}} loop.  How can I do this?

The HTML looks similar to this:

```
{{#each location}}
   <div>{{name}}</div>
   <div>{{calculated_distance}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

The JS:

```
Template.list.location = function (){
  return Collection.find({
    location : 
      { $near :
        { $geometry :
          { type : "Point",
            coordinates : [long, lat] },                
            $maxDistance: 430
        }}});
}
```

This only allows me to post the data in the collection. How do I access the {{calculated_distance}} for each document in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just use a helper:

```
Template.list.helpers ({
    calculated_distance: function() {
        var lat = this.location.coordinates.lat;
        var lng = this.location.coordinates.long;

        var someCalculation = ...

        return someCalculation;
    }
});
```

Inside a helper you have the context of `this` which would be a specific element in your `location`  collection (as you loop through them). In this helper you can calculate the distances you need and show them in your HTML. As it stands right now, your HTML is fine.

Comment: @Chromos yup no problem! Have fun with Meteor!